# How to swap the images in UIImageView programmatically

Tags: iphone

Hi i am beginner in iphone programming i am doing a photo gallery app. In which i need to apply swapping of array of images on UIImageView  along with zooming action.

can any one help me to do this by providing any sample codes or links..

Comment: You can try this link [Click Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ViewTransitions/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: hi i need to do as swapping the images by finger on touch...

Answer (score 0):

download try this code, i'm using it and it's well done:

[mwaterfall-MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser)

there's also the more complete Three20 Photo (search in github.com or in stackoverflow.com for old question), it has more kind of objects... but is also more complicated to be used...